# Set video as wallpaper on Android

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I want to know how to set Video as wallpaper or it is not possioble. I can set image as wallpaper and I can build live wallpaper but I can't set video as wallpaper ? so anyone has an idea how can I do that ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why not create a Live Wallpaper that plays a video?

Comment: possible but a battery killer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way that it can be done is to incorporate it into a "Live Wallpaper", the downside is as others have mentioned it will take a serious toll on battery life.

Answer (score 0):

this interesting, Live Wallpaper runs on Android 2.1 or higher.

http://mashable.com/2010/06/29/make-super-mario-bros-your-android-wallpaper-video/

> As cool as that is, we should note
>   that it will basically kill your
>   phone’s battery life.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, It is very much possible. In Android `MediaPlayer` Class, there is method `setSurface (Surface surface)`. Using this method you can play video on any surface. Get the surface from Wallpaper Engine and play video on this.