# Set any video as a wallpaper in android programmatically

Tags: android

I have a problem that I want to set a video file as a wallpaper in android device through code. But failed to find the exact method for the same on the web. I can set the static wallpaper with WallpaperManager Class in android and I don't know if we have a video file then how can we set it as a live wallpaper in android. Please suggest me the right solution regarding the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't believe there is a magic API function to do this. You'd have to write the live wallpaper yourself.

Comment: Means we can't set video file as a wallpaper in android.

Comment: @SanatPandey :one way you create a Live Wallpaper that play  a video..

Comment: @imrankhan which way you are talking about?

Comment: Maybe these Links help you - 

[Videa as wallpaper](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+%3A+video+as+wallpaper) &

[Video in wallpaper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448386/set-video-as-wallpaper-on-android) &

[Video as Live Wallpaper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825913/android-video-as-a-live-wallpaper)

Comment: i think you check this link may it help you[github](https://github.com/frankandrobot/FFvideoLiveWallpaper)